# Can my iOS app see the device's MDM certificate?

Tags: security, ipad, certificate, mdm

Is there a way for my application to see whether an MDM certificate/profile is deployed to the device it's running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  Applications cannot access the secure keychain, nor can they access profiles.