# Is it possible to implement MDM profile/certificate picking inside an iOS app?

Tags: ios, certificate, mdm

We are trying to implement a sort of SSL pinning using a certificate that is shared with all our devices using MDM.
The certificate is visible in device settings (General > Device Management > Profile under MDM section > More Details > list of certificates), but I can't find a way to use it inside an app.
Is this even possible using one of the existing iOS APIs?

I found some related but outdated questions in StackOverflow, saying that it is not possible, and not sure whether this functionality was added in later iOS versions.
[Example SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300623/can-my-ios-app-see-the-devices-mdm-certificate)

Thank you.